# Adding NgFor breaking Mat-line flex in angular 9

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, ngfor, mat-list

**I need to display like the example below**

[image]

**BUT when i add ngfor it breaks mat line flex row in to column.**

**HTML**

```
<mat-list *ngFor="let list of lists">
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let car of list.cars | keyvalue">
<h3 mat-line> {{car.key}} </h3>
<p mat-line *ngFor="let year of car.value">
<span> {{year}} </span>
</p>
<button mat-icon-button >
<mat-icon class="mat-24">delete</mat-icon>
</button>
</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

**TS**

```
export class ListSelectionExample {
lists = [
{
"cars":
{
 "12345": [1960, 1961],
 "4567": [2001, 2002]
}
}
]}
```

**Working example code here**
[Slackblitz.example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gv9dcr?file=src/app/list-selection-example.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
 <p mat-line >
    <span *ngFor="let year of car.value; let i = index"> {{year}}{{i==0?',':''}} </span>
  </p>
```

instead of

```
<p mat-line *ngFor="let year of car.value">
<span> {{year}} </span>
</p>
```

click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gv9dcr-rdrhmz?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.html) to view code

Comment: i have modified the answer